# How should I get rid of Appcompat Style while using Material Components?

Tags: android-appcompat, material-components-android

I am using BottomNavigationView in my project and my application is not suposed to support pre-Lollipop devices, so I didn't use the large appcompat library.But when I run my application it told me "The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant)."
So I want to know how can I get rid of Appcompat stuff and using Material components?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Get Started](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) instructions, using either AppCompatActivity or AppCompatDelegate is required.